# Graphdb/Neo4j relationship to another relationship, or relationship with 3 nodes

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I want to make IMDB's characters/roles structure in Neo4j. I'll need labels `Person`, `Movie` and `Character`. `Character`, because a character can be in multiple movies, played by different people.

Without `Character`, it's easy:

```
(Person)-[:PLAYS_IN]->(Movie)
```

But `PLAYS_IN` is a `Character`, so it would be something like:

```
(Person)-[:PLAYS_AS]->(Character)-[:PLAYS_IN]->(Movie)
```

but that doesn't work, because it doesn't have a direct `Person-Movie` relationship. Without that, everyone who ever played Peter Parker, is in every movie that has a Peter Parker.

There must be a Person-Movie relationship, but also a Person-Movie-Character relationship. How? This could work, but that's just nasty:

```
(Person)-[:PLAYS_IN {uuid}]->(Movie), (Character {uuid})
```

because now I'm creating my own foreign key kind of relationship. That's very ungraphdb. But it works:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:PLAYS_IN]->(m:Movie), (c:Character)
WHERE c.uuid = r.uuid
RETURN p, c, m
```

by building a cartesian product =( which is very RDBMS, but not very graphdb. And I can't query `Character-Movie` or `Character-Person`, because that's not a real relationship.

How do I make a RDBMS link table with 3 foreign keys (`movie_id, character_id, person_id`) in Neo4j??

**edit 1**
The RDBMS equivalent:

```
movies (id, title)                         # e.g. Dragon Tattoo, or Spider's Web
people (id, name)                          # e.g. Rooney Mara, or Claire Foy
characters (id, name)                      # e.g. Lisbeth Salander
roles (movie_id, person_id, character_id)  # 2 rows with 1 distinct character_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is solved by [hypergraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph). But since neo4j does not support hypergraphs, you need to model them. For example:

```
CREATE (P1:Person {name: 'Tobey Maguire'})
CREATE (P2:Person {name: 'Nicholas Hammond'})
CREATE (CW1:CreativeWork {name: 'Spider-Man'})
CREATE (CW2:CreativeWork {name: 'The Amazing Spider-Man (TV Series)'})
CREATE (CH:Character {name: 'Spider-Man'})

CREATE (A1:Role)
CREATE (A2:Role)

CREATE (P1)-[:PLAYS_AS]->(A1)
CREATE (A1)-[:HAS_CHARACTER]->(CH)
CREATE (A1)-[:PLAYS_IN]->(CW1)

CREATE (P2)-[:PLAYS_AS]->(A2)
CREATE (A2)-[:HAS_CHARACTER]->(CH)
CREATE (A2)-[:PLAYS_IN]->(CW2)
```

[image]

Comment: So `Role` is like a link table... Is that really the Neo4j way?? That's so inelegant!

Comment: How would I identify a node like that? Add uuid, or use `_id`, or by its relationships?

Comment: It feels very strange, an empty relationship node like this, but it works very well! This is more like it! https://www.screencast.com/t/nQLqDJEtw Is this the 'official' Neo4j way though?

Comment: It just feels weird, making a link table node in a graphdb. Link tables are necessary bad design in RDBMS. That's how graphdb advertises its own superiority. And now I'm making an empty node just for its foreign keys... Feels weird. But works perfectly!

Comment: @Rudie It depends on the point of view: the role in your case is not a concept that fits in the relationship between the actor and the film nodes. And if you expand it to a situation where a character is played by one actor and voiced by another, then everything falls into place.

Answer (score 1):

Make your relationship between `Actor` and `Movie` a [rich relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:annotating-entities:relationship-entity), where an `Actor` who `PLAYED_IN` a `Movie` plays a specific `Role`. The `Role` is implemented as a separate entity (relationship entity) with its own properties and only becomes an entity when the relationship between `Actor` and `Movie` exists.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Actor {
    Long id;
    @Relationship(type="PLAYED_IN") private Role playedIn;
}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "PLAYED_IN")
public class Role {
    @Id @GeneratedValue   private Long relationshipId;
    @Property  private String title;
    @StartNode private Actor actor;
    @EndNode   private Movie movie;
}

@NodeEntity
public class Movie {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
}
```

(token from the mentioned link)

Comment: I don't have code to annotate. I only have queries. How do I make a rich relationship with MATCH and CREATE? Your Role has an Actor and a Movie. That's the problem: a role/character can be reused across many movies, by many actors. I'll add a RDBMS equivalent in the question.