# Create Relationship Between three tables in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

Is it possible to create relationships between table1 with table3 by using table2?
for example in:

- Table1 we have id and momName
- Table2 we have id and table1ID and Table3ID
- Table3 we have id and dadName

we need to create relationship between mom and dad directly by just one type of relationship [:family] without showing the table2 nodes or relations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphdb/Neo4j relationship to another relationship, or relationship with 3 nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53064708/graphdb-neo4j-relationship-to-another-relationship-or-relationship-with-3-nodes)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
MATCH (t1:Table1), (t2:Table2), (t3:Table3)
WHERE t1.id = t2.table1ID AND t3.id = t2.table3ID
MERGE (t1)-[:family]-(t3)
```

For faster performance, you can first create [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on `:Table1(id)` and `:Table3(id)`.